# Opening a terminal from 14.04 Installation Disk

Tags: 14.04, command-line, system-installation, gnome-terminal

Does anybody know of a way to open a Terminal from the Ubuntu 14.04 Installation Disk? If so, is there a way to format a drive / clean it from then? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: The live mode is pretty much the same as an installed version of Ubuntu, and you can use GParted to format, no need for a terminal.

Comment: By the way, is gparted included by default on live cd / usb now or not ?

Answer (score 2):

To open a Terminal from the disk, choose "test Ubuntu" and just do as you would regularly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. You can still install Ubuntu from the test Ubuntu option.

If you want to format, clean, or partition your drive, you should use gparted which you can launch by typing `sudo gparted` and entering your password or running it from your applications. If you continue with your installation, you can also change/wipe/partition your hard drive using the "Other" method of installation, or just continue with the regular installation method and it will automatically do the partitioning.

Comment: You would rater execute `gparted-pkexec` which opens a GUI window to ask for the password. `gksu gparted` should also be fine. But `sudo` is usually only used for command line applications. I checked it and it would work, but it is not recommended and needs the password to be entered into the terminal.